# MPMusicPlayerController Play music while app is in background

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

Hope this question doesn't get down voted - I haven't seen anything in the documentation.

I want to play music from the ipod library while the app is in the back ground.

I am creating the music player using the default mechanism.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    MPMusicPlayerController *myPlayer =

    [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];



    // assign a playback queue containing all media items on the device

    [myPlayer setQueueWithQuery: [MPMediaQuery songsQuery]];



    // start playing from the beginning of the queue

    [myPlayer play];
}
```

As soon as the app enters the background the music stops playing. I would like it to continue playing though.

**I do not want to use the iPodMusicPlayer** option

How can I do this?

Comment: I was wondering if you ever sorted out a solution to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should set background audio mode in the project settings (Project settings > Capabilities > Background modes > Audio and AirPlay) like it's shown on the screenshot below:
[image]

Also you should set Audio Session Category in the appDelegate (in the didFinishLaunching method). Example is shown below:

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```

Comment: I understood the reason. You used applicationMusicPlayer but this player plays music only locally within your app. Try to use iPodMusicPlayer instead applicationMusicPlayer for play music in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. I searched even after added flag in plist. It will not work because :

> The `applicationMusicPlayer` does not support background music. Use
>   `MPMusicPlayerController's` **systemMusicPlayer** instead. It shares the
>   state with the built-in System player and music will continue to play
>   when your app enters the background.

**Other Solution is :**

You can use `AVAudioPlayer` to play either streamed or local(bundle) audio. It even allows you to play multiple audio file at the same time having an `AVAudioPlayer` instance for each.

**Note :**  `iPodMusicPlayer` is deprecated. so Instead of this use `systemMusicPlayer`.